# How do I know which dll is invoked in ASP page?

Tags: .net, dll, asp-classic, frameworks

I'd like to know how can I know which dll is invoked in "my" ASP page.

I saw in the code that there's a method who invoke a MyName.dll.

So I would know where I can find it?

Moreover I saw that in this path: C:\Inetpub\Dll\ there are 5 folders that represent 5 different release of the same dll (in every folder there are many files and 1 of them is  MyName.dll of the project every with the same name but different release)

while in  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 there is MyName.dll (but when I put the mouse over it I can see that the release is 1.0.0 so I thought that it is an old verion)

I feel very confused! 
I hope that somebody could give me an hand to resolve it.

Regards!

Comment: Is this definitely classic asp or is it asp.net?

Comment: Hi John, my pages are .asp but the dll (where there's the method who invoke a web service) is written in C#. I took this site from previous developers. Could be useful this? thanks!!!

Comment: If it's classic I'd think it would be whichever version of the dll has been registered.  There may be clues in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689072/how-to-check-if-a-dll-file-is-registered

Comment: I tried and I found in the registry all 5th dll's that I have in the path C:\Inetpub\Dll\... (in registry I've folders named 1.4.4.0, 1.4.4.1, 1.4.4.3... ) so my question is: which dll I need to modify if it seems that all of them are registered?

Comment: If you are using Classic ASP then you will calling the DLL through a `Server.CreateObject()` call at which point you usually specify a `ProgId`, for example `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"`. What is the `ProgId` you are trying to locate? Once you have it, you can use the Registry to identify the DLL that is registered against that `ProgId`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ASP Classic; in particular in code there's  var app= Server.CreateObject("NameDll.MethodDll"); and in MethodDll there is a method to invoke a WebService. So the problem is where I can found NameDll? I've many release of it in C:\Inetpub\Dll\.. with the same name so I don't know which of them was called by the page. Thanks

Comment: Calling a web service is completely different to calling a DLL.

Comment: Yes Paul, I know it, but I mean that in dll there is a method who needs to invoke a web service, that's all. I desire only know which dll I need to modify :/

Comment: Search the registry for the DLL name.

Comment: Couldn't you just register the version you want to use - that should override any previous registration

Comment: I solved the problem with Microsoft's Process Monitor. I lunched the page and I saw the net traffic; I analyzed it and I knew which dll is invoked. Now I would ask you this: if I modify this dll and I'll recompile it I need to registrate it? (With modifing I mean I would just change the Web Server URL). And if I need to register this new dll and for some reason something goes wrong, I'll be able to restore the old dll? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, whichever dll you registered most recently will be the one which is used, so you can re-register an old dll if necessary,  If you're recompiling then it's a good idea to keep a back up copy. (obviously).